# Remove array positions with eventListeners

Tags: arrays, loops, addeventlistener

I am not a developer, I do some javascript to do a/b testing so please excuse my lack of knowledge.

I'm looking to change the default cart quantities in an e-commerce application.
For various reasons I've come to the conclusion that I should build a copy of my cart in a js object, update it as my customer interacts with it to replace the defaults when the user accesses the cart.

I use this to set the default quantity to 20:

```
let myTable=[];
function test () {
myTable.push(20);
};
const addToCart = document.querySelectorAll(".outcomeButton");
for (i = 0; i < addToCart.length; i++) {
addToCart[i].addEventListener('click', test);
};
```

I then try to update my table if the user deletes an item from the cart:

```
const removeItem = document.querySelectorAll(".removeButton");
for (i = 0; i < removeItem.length; i++) {
removeItem[i].addEventListener('click', function removeFromTable () {
myTable.splice(i, 1);
});
};
```

Of course this doesn't work because when the user clicks on the delete button i has a fixed value.
And I also think that I should not use splice because it reindexes my table.

Can you help me ?